# How interface ( Object Oriented Programming concept) works in Python ? Also Please provide me some suitable example

Tags: python, django, interface, uml, component-diagram

How interface ( Object Oriented Programming concept) works in Python ? Also Please provide me some suitable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally Interfaces are used for linking two section(module) in application(s). I would call it a bunch(one or many) of method pointers.
You may face with interfaces to much when you are trying to contract with another module or application, because a standard way should be present here in order to making communication between two module.

---

Let say I have programmed a module about listening on a certain files in OS, and you would to use my module. so how do we need understand each other?! there is a possible solution, you would pass a method pointer(interface) to my module, then my module will trigger(invoke) the pointer as event occurred.
so the first thing we need here is defining the interface(method pointer)
[image: Listener Interface]

```
//code: java
public interface Listener{
 void onEvent(String fileName);
}
```

in above interface, there is one method defined. the `onEvent` method is called when a file gets changed. this method has an argument `String fileName` which points to the file name has changed.

---

So here, my module uses(invokes) the interface, and your modules implements it. so this is the point, we could interact with each other by interfaces.

So for such this scenarios the UML diagram would be like this.
My modules requires the interface.
Your module implements the interface.
[image: Ring-Bell model]

As interface code example above, as you see, the interface is nothing itself, it acts liek a pointer, but it ensure the target class(MyModule) that the target class has a method called `onEevent`.

I hope I could give some hand.

Comment: Thanks by explanation. But I still have a doubt. This concept also works in python or java,c#... ?Can I do the same thing in python?

Comment: yes of course, interfaces are very useful when you are implementing modules/libraries, because the whole complex system is known with some interfaces. and this is not belong just to Java, but c# uses delegates instead of interfaces while i supports interfaces too.